# How to use getElementsByTagName Effeciently

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently using this bookmarklet to hide several random rows of a webpage:

```
(function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[3].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[6].style.display = "none";
})();
```

Is it necessary to repeat

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[].style.display = "none"
```

again and again or is there any way to simplify it ?
I mean to merge all these into a simple command like

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1,3,6].style.display = "none".
```

Is it possible?

Kindly provide me an example coding for above bookmarklet?

Comment: what about use jquery?

Comment: Drop it into a variable and then iterate over it.

Comment: You can save the returned value in  variable and then use the variable instead of calling the function over and over again.

Comment: Can anyone provide me an example coding?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method/42379723#42379723

Comment: @Kinduser Would you consider this a duplicate then?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes it is. But no one cares about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I don't see how that's a duplicate. The OP already knows that an indexed collection is returned.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you are trying to do, most likely a more CSS-centric way. What is your goal? Do you want to hide the first three rows of some table?

Comment: @squint I think so because [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10693852/989920) shows how to use the HTMLCollection. All the OP need do is swap out the for loop variables.

Comment: Please do not ask "is it possible?". Everything is possible--we are working with computers, which can be programmed. You probably meant to ask "is there a way to do this?". Also, you may want to look at how to use a dictionary or spellchecker (on your title) efficiently. Anyway, the answer to your question is to use the Programming 101 concept known as a "loop".

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can store the `tr`s in a variable:

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

Then you can loop through the `tr`s 1 through 3.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  trs[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Alternately, you can use `Array.prototype.slice` to select a range of `tr`s.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(trs, 1, 4).forEach(function(tr) {
  tr.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Unless something has changed, you can't slice `trs` directly. You'll need to borrow `Array.prototype.slice`.

Comment: ...however, modern implementations seem to be adding `.forEach()` directly, so you could compare the index inside the callback as an alternative.

Comment: This is technically speaking a good answer to the question, but it's almost never necessary to loop over something and set styles explicitly like this. CSS can handle almost all such cases, and we could tell the OP how to do that if he told us what his actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var rows= document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
Array.from(rows).forEach(v => v.style.display = 'none');
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a for loop or foreach loop.

```
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
    temp[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

or

```
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
temp.forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
```

Can be put into

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tr").forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
```

Comment: That's not your question. You want to do one thing for every element without repeating.

Comment: A table row doesn't have a prototype method `doSomething()`. your code will simply throw an error

Comment: And now your answer is getting insanely wrong. foreach = forEach, and a htmlCollection doesn't have this prototype

Comment: Man, serious? You have to fill that in yourself. Something like `row.style.display = "none"`

Comment: Do you really want me to change it?

Comment: Your answer is completely wrong. Yes you should change it, did you try to run this code?

Comment: @MadhusoodanP: There really is quite a lot wrong with this. `foreach`, `documetn`, declaring with `int`, and not targeting the subset of elements described in the question for starters. I'd be curious to know why the positive points.